# Position a node to the right of a subgraph with graphviz

Tags: position, graphviz, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm using `graphviz` to plot the DAG of a simple latent variable model:

```
digraph G {

    splines=line;

    subgraph cluster {
        node [style=filled, shape=circle];
        edge [color=blue]
        z[fillcolor=white, color=black, pos = "0,0!"]
        z -> x;
    }

    theta[label = "θ", shape=circle, pos = "10,0!"]
    edge [color=black, style="dashed"]
    theta->z
    theta->x

}
```

The output is decent:

[image]

but I'd like θ to be at the same height as z. Is that possible? I tried to use the `pos` attribute, but as you see, it's nicely ignored. I'm working in [HackMD](https://hackmd.io/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [constraint](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:constraint)`=false` attribute to your `theta` edges so they won't affect layout and nodes will remain side by side:

```
digraph G {

    splines=line;

    subgraph cluster1 {
        node [style=filled, shape=circle];
        edge [color=blue]
        z[fillcolor=white, color=black, pos = "0,0!"]
        z -> x;
    }
    theta[label = "θ", shape=circle, pos = "10,0!"]
    edge [color=black, style="dashed"]
    theta -> z [constraint=false]
    theta -> x [constraint=false] // actually this one is unnecessary, may be omited in this example

}
```

[image]

Also, you may experiment with edge direction (e.g. change places a->b, b->a), this sometimes helps with positioning clusters.